# flex + AIR nativewindow minimize

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

In my Flex AIR desktop application I am opening a nativewindow(a window component). On a button click I am explicitly minimizing the nativeWindow using: nativeWindow.minimize();

It minimizes the window that is fine but after that if I traces the nativeWindow.x &  nativeWindow.y, they comes as -3200, -3200. due to this I am unable to restore the window again. I have to close the window then open again. No other option to restore.

I tried to capture the event of minimize/restore, didn't get any help.

Please help, I am stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NativeWindow does includes a method called restore() to restore a minimized/maximized window programmatically. Check the documentation at,

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#restore()